# Adding Column taking time in oracle11g

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am altering table by adding a column it is taking time.  it has around 20,000 rows

My alter script is

```
ALTER TABLE TABLE_NAME1 ADD ADD_COLUMN1 VARCHAR2(50);
```

I have checked my Locks on table it doesnot have any locks excpet the alter table commnad locks

```
 select * from dba_dml_locks where NAME='TABLE_NAME1'
```

Mode_held column in above query gives **Row-X (SX)**

Comment: What does "taking time" mean? Does it finish but longer than you expect. Does it wait forever?

Comment: its running for long time.Now almost 2 hours

Comment: Make sure there is no other session that has a transaction running on that table. commit or rollback any other session.

Comment: there are no other sessions. Is it because it has referential integerity on many other tables?

Answer (score 0):

In my observation ddl in Oracle is slow. To compress your script you could add more columns per alter statement like

```
Alter myrable add (col1 type1, col2 type2)
```

This could speed up your script.